# How to use my own DNS settings as an OpenVPN client?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, dns, openvpn

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I’m connecting to a VPN server using OpenVPN via Gnome Network Manager. I prefer to use OpenNic as my DNS but my VPN provider uses Google Public DNS. My OpenNic DNS settings work great without VPN. However, when I connect to my VPN provider I am forced to use their DNS settings (Google). Is there any way for me to override their DNS settings and use my own?

Also, I would still like my DNS requests to be routed through my VPN. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

When using a VPN you are locked in to the VPN provider's infrastructure. If they are not allowing split DNS, you must use theirs. This is by design and there's no way that you can circumvent it if the provider does not allow it.